# How to check if user input is String, double or long in Java

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner in java. I want to check first if the user input is String or Double or int. If it's String, double or a minus number, the user should be prompted to enter a valid int number　again. Only when the user entered a valid number should then the program jump to try. I've been thinking for hours and  I come up with nothing useful.Please help, thank you!

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fizz {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please enter a number");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {

        Integer i = scan.nextInt();

        if (i % 3 == 0 && (i % 5 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fizz");
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Buzz");
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + "は3と5の倍数ではありません。");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("");

    } finally {
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But where should I add the code? I tried adding it and I get an error.Could you please reply with your code added to my code?Thanks again!

Comment: Replace the line `Integer i = scan.nextInt();` with the code by @TheLostMind and after his block (don't forget the  `;` after his code) add the line `int = Integer. parseInt(s);`

Comment: Thanks so much! It compiles and run good now!

Comment: Please don't foget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 9):

One simple fix is to read the entire line / user input as a String.
Something like this should work. (Untested code) :

```
   String s=null;
   boolean validInput=false; 
   do{
      s= scannerInstance.nextLine();
      if(s.matches("\\d+")){// checks if input only contains digits
       validInput=true;
      }
      else{
       // invalid input
     }
    }while(!validInput);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Scanner.nextInt` throw an exception if the input was not a number? It would be easier to just catch that exception right?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik - But that is not the right way to do it. :).. Why catch exceptions when you can execute code without them?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik  It could be that the string starts with an integer, but contains other characters as well. And it therefore also doesn't check if a double was given, since it would cut of at the end of the integer. It would also corrupt further input.

Comment: LBYL vs. EAFP I guess :D

Comment: What about [`scannerInstance.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) ?

Comment: @coolcat007: Yes, that's true. So nextLine() is the way to go.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar - because `nextInt()` accepts negative numbers..  :)

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar - I am saying that `hasNextInt()` returns `true` for *negative* numbers as well. and OP doesn;t want that

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar "What about `scannerInstance.hasNextInt()`" same reason as the one I described before for `nextInt`. It would imply that you also have to check if the rest of the buffer is empty (did the input scanner encounter a newline?) and if the value isn't negative. Much more lines of code needlessly written, when you could have used the one-liner `s.matches("\\d+")`

Comment: @TheLostMind You forgot the semicolon at the end after the do while.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Integer.parseInt and then check that integer for non negativity. You can catch NumberFormatException if the input is string or a double.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
     String s = scan.nextLine();
     int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: What about negative integers?

Comment: It will need additional check for negative integers after checking that it is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I used some conditions to indicate the input.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
int charCount = input.length();
boolean flag = false;
for(int x=0; x<charCount; x++){   
   for(int y=0; y<10; y++){
       if(input.charAt(x)==Integer.toString(y))
          flag = true;
       else{
          flag = false;
          break;
       }
   }
}
if(flag){
   if(scan.hasNextDouble())
      System.out.println("Input is Double");
   else
      System.out.println("Input is Integer");
}   
else
   System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Input a number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will prompt for input until an `int` greater than 0 is entered:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number");

try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        int number;
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            number = scan.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
            scan.next();
            continue;
        }

        if (number < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number > 0");
            continue;           
        }

        //At this stage, the number is an int >= 0
        System.out.println("User entered: " + number);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean valid = false;
double n = 0;
String userInput = "";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(!valid){
    System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
    userInput = input.nextLine();

    try{
        n = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        valid = true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println("Enter the valid number.");
    }
}
```