# Is there a String equivalent in java to input.hasNextInt?

Tags: java, string, input

I'm used to checking if a user inputs a double or a integer with `input.hasNextDouble`/`input.hasNextIn`t and then assigning a variable if this is true with `input.nextDouble`()/`input.nextInt()`.

But now I want to check if the input is a String or not, and if so, assign my variable, and if not, produce an error message and loop again. Is there an equivalent method/statement like this for Strings in Java? Or another way to do so?

Comment: `"But now I want to check if the input is a String or not,..."` -- the input is always a String, either that or empty, but even that is an empty String `""` -- please clarify **exactly** what you're testing.

Comment: So is `"1234"` a `String`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692089/how-to-check-if-user-input-is-string-double-or-long-in-java has numerous explanations/ways of checking for numerical input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java Check this

Answer (score 0):

A [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html) allows you to read in text from some sort of input (e.g. a file or an `InputStream`).  That text is naturally a `String` (because it's a sequence of bytes, which `Scanner` interprets as characters).  You can read the strings with `.next()` and `.nextLine()`, which read a single "word" token or a single line at a time, and which you can inspect with `hasNext()` and `hasNextLine()`.

`Scanner` also provides the primitive methods as a convenience for reading in tokens that can be safely converted into primitives (e.g. `int` and `double`), so that you don't have to write convoluted integer-parsing code and the like.

But if all you need is strings, just use `hasNext()` and `next()`, or `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`. There is no need to check whether the input is a `String` or not, because anything the user types is a string.  Be sure to read the docs describing how `Scanner` splits words/tokens up as well.

Answer (score -3):

If you use an IDE like Eclipse, it should show you the options after you type `input.`. Anyway, the boolean check for strings in the Scanner class would either be:

`input.hasNext();`

or

`input.hasNext();`

where input is an instance of the Scanner class

Comment: Which is basically the same name twice