# Sum of Multiple integers

Tags: java

I am a newbie at programming and Java, I have this program that calculate sum of inputs that's okay but I need to end this loop by typing "=", any suggestion?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int input;
        int sum = 0;
        String s = "=";
        System.out.println("Enter Num");

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            input=sc.nextInt();
            sum+=input;
            if( ){break;}       
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

and if there any suggestion making this program better performance it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the tokens as `String`(s) in order to test if your `input` is an `=`. Something like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
String input;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter Num");
    input = sc.next();
    if (input.matches("\\d+")) { // <-- sanity check for digits.
        try {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
} while (!input.equals("="));
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read a string by using sc.nextLine() and use the string.matches method to determine wether the input is a digit or '='. Example for matching digit [How to check if user input is String, double or long in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692089/how-to-check-if-user-input-is-string-double-or-long-in-java):

```
   String s=null;
   boolean validInput=false; 
   do{
      s= scannerInstance.nextLine();
      if(s.matches("\\d+")){// checks if input only contains digits
       validInput=true;
      }
      else{
       // invalid input
     }
    }while(!validInput);
```

Comment: The String.matches function compares two strings and if the strings are the same it returns true. You can also check if it matches a regular expression like the one in the example. So in your case you would check if the input is a digit and if it is a digit cast it to an integer and add it to your other int sum and else if s.matches("=")  then you break the loop. I would also change the for loop to a do while loop

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try following. It should have the same result as what you are trying:

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
int input;
int sum=0;
String inStr="";
System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    inStr=sc.next();
    if(!inStr.equals("="))
    {
        input=Integer.parseInt(inStr);
        System.out.println("input=="+input);
        sum+=input;
        System.out.println("sum ASON=="+sum);
    }
    else
        break;

}
System.out.println("sum==="+sum);
```